# Dodging points and error bars with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this data (note that `foo` is actually a factor.):

```
foo bar outcome ci
1   a   0.683333333 0.247447165
2   b   0.941666667 0.180356565
3   c   0.783333333 0.335337789
1   d   0.866666667 0.204453706
2   e   0.45    0.303059647
3   f   0.325   0.340780173
```

I want to plot multiple `bar`s per `foo` value, with their `outcome` and error bars with CI. Here's what I do:

```
ggplot(ex, aes(foo, outcome, label = bar)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(.1)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = outcome - ci, ymax = outcome + ci), position = position_dodge(.1)) + 
  geom_text(hjust = 2)
```

I get:

[image]

But I wanted it to dodge the error bars and points so I can see the overlap. [Using `position_jitter` did that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281027/dodge-not-working-when-using-ggplot2), but it was totally random (or ["clunky"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874376/position-dodge-with-error-bars-in-ggplot2)) — I don't want that.

How can I offset the individual observations?

Or is this a bug with ggplot? The [example here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/position_dodge.html) also [shows this error](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/position_dodge-15.png).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One possibility is to `group` by 'bar'. Note that I also `dodge` the `geom_text`.

```
dodge <- position_dodge(.1)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = foo, y = outcome, group = bar, label = bar)) + 
  geom_point(position = dodge) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = outcome - ci, ymax = outcome + ci), position = dodge) + 
  geom_text(hjust = 2, position = dodge)
```

[image]

Comment: Briliant, thanks. Can you point me to the documentation of `group` or explain why it works (or what it does) in this case?

Comment: @slhck, You may have a look at the help text at `?aes_group_order`, or [**here**](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_group_order.html) where you also find the output of all examples.